# http and https issue with domain and sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

We got a ssl for domain for example **www.sample.com** so it is working fine with **https://www.sample.com** and we created a sub-domain like **sub.sample.com** and it is working fine with **http://sub.sample.com** and **https://sub.sample.com**. But if we are giving **www** infront of the subdomain with **https** like **https://www.sub.sample.com**. It is accessing the main domain's home page. Can anyone please explain me what is the problem??

Comment: Post your current .htaccess code.

Comment: What does your current .htaccess contain? There might be a rule enforcing www. on the main domain which also applies mistakenly to the subdomain.

Comment: If i 'https' it is not accessing sub-domain folder.it is accessing only the main domain files

Comment: THat is understood but whatever code you have in .htaccess post it in your question.